# Additional custom fields with the default com_user fieldset

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I know many questions exist about the addition of new fields for registration and user profiles with the solution being to create a custom profile plugin. However, any plugin will create a new fieldset that will be displayed underneath the default fieldset.

Is it possible to, let's say, replace "name" with two new fields "first name" and "last name" without butchering the com_user files directly? I want these new fields to be together with the default fields.

Comment: You don't have to loop through the xml, you can echo the fields by hand where ever you want in a layout override.

Comment: Ok but won't I need to actually modify the com_user so that it inserts and retrieves from the table, and displays the fields in the backend?

Comment: No do it in a layout override. The looping is just useful for when you don't know what to expect. In your site you know what you want.

Comment: Could you point me to some documentation as to which class I should be using?

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core